# Is it possible, and how to search in date fields

Tags: search

When working with custom date fields, are there any solutions for searching dates? e.g. channel:entries search:datefield=""

The only thing that seems to work, if you search for the litteral unix timestamp e.g. 1394967600

**Edit/clarfication**
I'm searching for a way to use `>` and `<` for custom date ranges based on custom fields. The start_on and stop_before parameters only work on the entry_date.

Answer compilation:
- **Query module** (however, you won't be able to use other channel:entries parameters)
- SolSpace **Date Field Filter** (ads parameters to channel:entries tag)
- **Low-Search** (allows ranges on custom fields)

Answer (score 3):

With `entry_date` you can use a `start_on` and `stop_before` parameter in your channel loop but cannot do an equivalent for custom date fields.

You have two good options here. The first is to use the `{exp:query}` module in place of a channel entry loop, and the other is to use a third-party search module such as [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search)

If you opt for the query method you should start a loop such as the following...

```
<ul>
    {exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_channel_data JOIN exp_channel_titles 
 ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id WHERE (exp_channel_data.channel_id = '7') AND (field_id_48 > '1194712120' AND field_id_48 < '1694712120')"}
        <li>{title} - {field_id_48}</li>

        {if no_results}
          <li>No results :-(</li>
        {/if}
    {/exp:query}
</ul>
```

Where `'7'` is your channel ID and `field_id_48` is the ID of your date field.

You can also change the second reference to `field_id_48` to a date field for "end date".

Change `1194712120` and `1694712120` to the correct UNIX time stamp for your date range.

The query module is free and built into ExpressionEngine, but you may need to enable it via the "Add-Ons > Module" screen in the control panel. Low Search is a paid for third-party add-on.

Comment: The query module is an option, but then you lose all functionality of the channel:entries module tag (you don't want to build your own category subqueries yourself in there). Low-search is currently the best option i think, but not free. Also i found Solspace Date-filter, which extends the channel:entries tag.

Answer (score 2):

GDmac

I think you can workaround this problem using a simple php code like

```
$timestamp = $this->EE->localize->string_to_timestamp("May 20th, 2007");
```

this will give you a timestamp value for your date which can by passed to {channel:entries} loop via embed variable.

or you can put it in a simple plugin if you don't want to use php.

you can use my plugin https://github.com/ahmad-saad/str_to_time

I hope this will help you

Regard's.